# If I scroll the listview, part of the item are not visible in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I made a web service with flutter, if you scroll down and up the listview, you can't see some items.
This doesn't happens on the desktop web, it only happens on mobile (via web). (It's not a mobile app)

It's okay when I scroll for the first time, but if I scroll many times, this happens

I made it using ListView.builder, is there a related problem? The value of the item exists well as you can see

[image]

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_front/common/component/container/responsive_container.dart';
import 'package:flutter_front/common/styles/colors.dart';
import 'package:flutter_front/common/styles/sizes.dart';
import 'package:flutter_front/common/styles/text_styles.dart';
import 'package:flutter_front/user_management/common/info_list.dart';
import 'package:flutter_front/user_management/model/entity/user_info_entity.dart';
import 'package:flutter_front/user_management/model/state/user_list_state.dart';
import 'package:flutter_front/user_management/viewmodel/user_list_viewmodel.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';

class UserListView extends ConsumerStatefulWidget {
const UserListView({super.key});

@override
ConsumerState<UserListView> createState() => _UserListViewState();
}

class _UserListViewState extends ConsumerState<UserListView> {
@override
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  if (ref.read(userListViewmodelProvider.notifier).state
      is! UserListStateSuccess) {
    Future(
      () => ref.read(userListViewmodelProvider.notifier).getUserList(),
    );
  }
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  final viewmodel = ref.watch(userListViewmodelProvider);
  switch (viewmodel.state.runtimeType) {
    case UserListStateSuccess:
      return viewmodel.userList!.isNotEmpty
          ? ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                if ((viewmodel.searchCircle == circleListForSearch[0] ||
                        viewmodel.userList![index].circle_circle_name ==
                            viewmodel.searchCircle) &&
                    (viewmodel.searchMajor == majorListForSearch[0] ||
                        viewmodel.userList![index].major_major_name ==
                            viewmodel.searchMajor) &&
                    (viewmodel.searchName == "" ||
                        viewmodel.userList![index].member_user_name
                            .contains(viewmodel.searchName))) {
                  return userListItemContainer(
                    userInfo: viewmodel.userList![index],
                    onTap: () => viewmodel.selectedItem(index),
                    isSelected: viewmodel.selectedIndex == index,
                  );
                } else {
                  return Container(
                    height: 0,
                  );
                }
              },
              itemCount: viewmodel.userList!.length)
          : Center(
              child: Text(
                "사용자가 없습니다",
                style: kTextMainStyle.copyWith(
                  fontSize: kTextTitleSize,
                ),
              ),
            );
    case UserListStateLoading:
      return const Center(
        child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
      );
    case UserListStateError:
      return const Center(
        child: Text("에러가 발생했습니다"),
      );
  }
  return Container();
}
}

Widget userListItemContainer({
required UserInfo userInfo,
required VoidCallback onTap,
bool isSelected = false,
}) {
return Padding(
  padding: EdgeInsets.only(
    bottom: kPaddingMiniSize,
  ),
  child: GestureDetector(
    onTap: onTap,
    child: Container(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
        vertical: kPaddingMiniSize,
      ),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: isSelected ? kMainColor : null,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(kBorderRadiusSize),
      ),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
        children: [
          renderInfoContainer(
              info: userInfo.member_user_name, isSelected: isSelected),
          renderInfoContainer(
              info: userInfo.circle_circle_name, isSelected: isSelected),
          renderInfoContainer(
              info: userInfo.major_major_name, isSelected: isSelected),
          renderInfoContainer(
              info: userInfo.member_phone_number, isSelected: isSelected),
          Icon(
            Icons.keyboard_arrow_right_outlined,
            size: kIconMiddleSize,
            color: isSelected ? kBackgroundMainColor : kTextMainColor,
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
}

Widget renderInfoContainer({
required String info,
bool isSelected = false,
}) {
return Expanded(
  child: Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: SingleChildScrollView(
          scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: Text(
            info,
            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            style: kTextNormalStyle.copyWith(
              fontSize: kTextMiddleSize,
              color: isSelected ? kBackgroundMainColor : kTextMainColor,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      ResponsiveSizedBox(size: kPaddingMiddleSize),
    ],
  ),
);
}
```

Comment: Please Attach its code for better understanding.

Comment: Most probably you need to define safe area  or SizedBox container to match the list

Answer (score 1):

You Can add Padding in ListView at Bottom So It Will Start Showing.

E.g.

```
ListView.builder(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
    itemCount: 1,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
       return Container();
    },
)
```